# Incompatible return type error java

Tags: java

```
class BankAccount {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int ssn;
    private int accountnumber = 0;
    private double accountbalance = 0.0;

    BankAccount() {
        firstname = "John Smith";
    }

    BankAccount(String firstname, String lastname, int ssn) {
        int accountnumber;
        double accountbalance;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return accountbalance;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(int accountnumber) {
        return accountnumber;
    }

    public boolean equals(BankAccount ba) {
        return this.accountbalance == ba.accountbalance;
    }

    public void deposit(double amount) {
        return this.accountbalance = this.accountbalance + amount;
    }

    public int withdraw(double amount) {
        this.accountbalance = this.accountbalance - amount;
        if(accountbalance < 0) {
            this.accountbalance = this.accountbalance + amount;
            return -1;
        }
        else
           return 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return firstname+lastname+"/n"+"social secuirty "+"ssn"+"/n"+"account number is "+
        "accountnumber" +"/n" +"Balance:" +"accountbalance" +"/n";
    }
}
```

Error is :

```
BankAccount.java:34: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
return accountnumber;
       ^
BankAccount.java:47: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
return this.accountbalance=this.accountbalance+amount;
                          ^
2 errors
```

What am I doint wrong?

Comment: you are returning wrong.

Comment: Formatting your code will not only make it easier for others to see problems with your code, but for you to see them as well.

Comment: The compiler error is quite helpful.  Returning a value is unexpected because you declared the methods as `void`, which means they cannot return any values.

Answer (score 7):

A `void` method cannot `return` someting. And a method which have a return type must `return` the type specified in method signature.

**Error 1**

For example look this method

```
 public void setAccountNumber(int accountnumber) {
   return accountnumber;
   }
```

Yo cannot return from a `void` method.

That should be

```
  public void setAccountNumber(int accountnumber) {
           this.accountnumber =accountnumber;
       }
```

Same goes for remaining methods too.

**Error 2**

```
public void deposit(double amount) {
        return this.accountbalance = this.accountbalance + amount;
    }
```

that return statement is syntactically wrong. You cannot return as it is void. That should be

```
  public void deposit(double amount) {
            this.accountbalance = this.accountbalance + amount;
        }
```

Comment: `You cannot declare variables in constructor` Why not? Although it is clearly wrong code in semantic, but isn't there no problem in this *in syntax*?

Comment: Re: error 1, you can declare variables in a constructor, it's just that it's unlikely this ctor is doing what the OP expects.

Comment: Also, the `return` statement w/ the assignment isn't syntactically wrong.

Comment: @ikh Yes. I cross checked it. Edited.

Comment: I don't see an edit; the syntax is correct, it's the return type v. method declaration that's wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton I did'nt get you. Anyways, I given the correct code as well.

Comment: A `void` method can `return;`.

Comment: @FabianBarney I mean `return something` :)

Comment: There's nothing syntactically wrong with `return this.accountbalance = this.accountbalance + amount;`, it's valid syntax.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void setAccountNumber(int accountnumber) {
 return accountnumber;
 }
```

here your return type is `void` and your returning `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setAccountNumber(int accountnumber) {
    return accountnumber;
}

public void deposit(double amount) {
    return this.accountbalance=this.accountbalance+amount;
}
```

...Are you trying to return in `void`-return function???

This will be correct:

```
public int setAccountNumber(int accountnumber) {
//     ^^^
    return accountnumber;
}

public double deposit(double amount) {
//     ^^^^^^
    return this.accountbalance=this.accountbalance+amount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forst Error is that the return type of your meyhod is `void` and the method returns an `int`.

```
 public void setAccountNumber(int accountnumber) {
    return accountnumber;
 }
```

Change it to :

```
 public int setAccountNumber(int accountnumber) {
    return accountnumber;
 }
```

and the second thing is **this is not a good name for a method which is used for getting the variable** , change the name of method to :

```
 public int getAccountNumber(int accountnumber) { // why is this argument???
    return accountnumber;
 }
```

**One more thing,** your method

```
public void deposit(double amount) {
     return this.accountbalance = this.accountbalance + amount;
}
```

has the same error. It should be :

```
public double deposit(double amount) { //change void to double
    return this.accountbalance + amount; //as suggested by SURESH ATTA
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every answer so far is correct and points out problems.  Here is one that is not yet mentioned.

Your `equals` method does not properly over-ride the parent:

```
public boolean equals(BankAccount ba) {
    return this.accountbalance == ba.accountbalance;
}
```

The signature of `equals` on `Object` is `public boolean equals(Object other)` so that any objects can be compared to each other.  You have changed it to only allow comparing against other BankAccounts, which violates the contract.

Try this instead:

```
public boolean equals(BankAccount ba) {
    if (ba instanceof BankAccount) {
        return this.accountbalance == ((BankAccount) ba).accountbalance;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```